# angle between two planes, why can we use the dot product?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

I understand that to find the angle we use the dot product of the normal vectors of the two planes, but why is it correct? as the normal vectors are both 90 degrees from the "real" angle of the planes

Comment: Place 2 toothpicks on a sheet of paper. Now, turn the sheet of paper $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

The [dihedral angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) between two intersecting planes is the angle between the lines of intersection of the given planes with a third plane perpendicular to their line of intersection.

So this plane contains the normal vectors of the two planes and the angle between the planes is the same as the angle between these two orthogonal vectors ( since the angle between two lines is the same as the angle between two orthogonal lines).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're viewing the planes from 'side on' (ie straight along the line of intersection), so they appear as lines. If you now rotate the angle that you see through 90 degrees, you'll effectively be looking at the angle between the normals because, as you say, the normals are each at 90 degrees to their respective planes.